# ckeditor and display users data as they type

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have a textarea that as the user enters data into the textarea, the data is displayed at the bottom of the form as a display of how their data may appear (much in the same way that StackOverflow gives a preview display of the users question as the user types it).

I have installed CKEditor 4.3.1 to this textarea and the preview display no longer appears.

I assumed that this was because the id of the text area had been replaced by the id of the CKEditor, so I tried replacing the id of the text area with the id of the CKEditor, but this approach did not work.

Is my thinkg wrong? I have read the CKEditor docs, but found nothing to help me.

What approach should I use to display the data as the user enters their data into the CKEditor?

Comment: you can use class or name to identify texteditor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because CKEditor runs **next to** your `<textarea>` in DOM (hides it first) and, in a matter of fact, it doesn't update contents of your `<textarea>` unless you request it or destroy the editor. That's how CKEditor works.

Call [`editor.updateElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement) to synchronize `<textarea>` with rich editor contents. You can use [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event to `updateElement` periodically and keep things in sync.

What might be the problem is that, quite likely, your existing code observes keyboard events (`onkeyup`, `onkeydown`) fired in `<textarea>` and updates the preview at the bottom of your page. You need to re-attach those callbacks to [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event because CKEditor doesn't trigger any events in `<textarea>` (as I mentioned, it doesn't interact with it at all). So there are two ways of solving your problem:

1. On [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) call [`editor.updateElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-updateElement) and fire keyboard event from code on `<textarea>` (see [**the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/8WbCB/)).

   ```
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
       plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar,undo',
       on: {
           instanceReady: function() {
               // Show textarea for dev purposes.
               this.element.show();
           },
           change: function() {
               // Sync textarea.
               this.updateElement();    

               // Fire keyup on <textarea> here?
           }
       }
   } );
   ```
2. Attach existing preview update callbacks to [`editor#change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change).

I'm for 2. since 1. is a kind of hack. But it's up to you, of course.

Comment: Thnaks for such a detailed response. This helped me.

Comment: @oleq How do I replace all textareas with ckeditor and have all the corresponding hidden textareas update on change?

Comment: Link to the fiddle in the answer.