# How to make CKEditor update hidden textarea with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a textarea as such:

```
<textarea name="Circumstances" id="Circumstances"> </textarea>
```

I have turned this into a CKEditor textarea using this:

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace( 'Circumstances' );
</script>
<script>My JQuery Stuff Goes Here</script>
```

I need to update the hidden textarea with the data from the CKEditor instance while a user is typing or on blur. I would like to do this using JQuery if possible. My problem is that I don't know how to do it and I also don't know what the instance name of the CKEditor is for the textarea. I guessed it was the same as the ID for the textarea. So I tried this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[Circumstances].on('blur', function(event) {
for(var Circumstances in CKEDITOR.instances)
CKEDITOR.instances[ExtenuatingCircumstances].updateElement();
}
```

But the above doesn't do anything for me. Any suggestions please??

Comment: possible duplicate of [ckeditor and display users data as they type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581720/ckeditor-and-display-users-data-as-they-type)

Comment: thank you oleq surprised I didn't find that

Comment: @oleq how do I change all textareas in a form to CKEditor and also have it update the hidden element on change?

Comment: I've done it, will post as self-answer in new topic

Comment: I am desperate to see how you did this. I could not locate your self-answer topic. Can you link to it?

Comment: @user1261774 PM me and I'll see if I can help you. Its been a while since I did it but I made it work.

Comment: Thanks for the offer - I appreciate it, but I got the issue solved.

Comment: Here is the solution - I hope it helps someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035396/ckeditor-content-into-textarea-on-change-event-beginner/22036484#22036484