# ckeditor content into textarea on change event - beginner

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to get the contents of my ckeditor to be entered into the associated textarea as the user enters the value into the ckeditor.

I have read several helpful threads, namely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581720/ckeditor-and-display-users-data-as-they-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143516/detecting-onchange-events-from-a-ckeditor-using-jquery), but I am going around in circles as my code experience and knowledge is not so great.

I understand how the ckeditor works and that I should be using the change event as described in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581720/ckeditor-and-display-users-data-as-they-type).

I have managed to add the following jquery code to display the alert message when the user enters value into the ckeditor:

```
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() {alert('value changed!!')});
    }
```

My text area code is:

```
<textarea id="id_a_description" rows="10" cols="40" name="a_description" class="input-95pc" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
```

**How do I change the jquery code above to enter the value from the ckeditor into the text area  as the users types using the ckeditor change event?**

This would really help me out as I am so frustrated at not being able to solve this even-though I think I am very close to the solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling this function in the onchange event

```
CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
```

Comment: Whoa!!! Correction! This is the correct answer. My poor coding skills got it wrong. Then I re-tried it and it works. Thanks.

Comment: haha I was going to create a fiddle for you but good you got it to work :)

Comment: just posted a related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063508/ckeditor-content-into-textarea-on-change-event-multiple-ckeditors-on-form