# ckeditor content into textarea on change event - multiple ckeditors on form

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

With a lot of help I finally got the CKEditor to update the associated text area. [See the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035396/ckeditor-content-into-textarea-on-change-event-beginner).

However, I am stumped of how to get the CKEditor to update each associated text area when there is more than 1 CKEditor on the form.

Here is the jquery that I currently have. It only updates the last CKEditor associated text area on the form:

```
    for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[i].on('change', function() { CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement() }); //update the relative hidden textarea.
    }
```

**How do I update each associated CKEditor text area when I have 5 or 10 CKEditors on the form?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For each instance of the ckeditor that you want to install on your page, add the following code to your jquery script:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['id_of_text_area'].on('change', function() { CKEDITOR.instances['id_of_text_area'].updateElement() });
```

The above JavaScript should replace the code I have displayed in the original question.

I hope this will help some one.

Comment: Finally, you're the only person whose posted an answer that works across the internet.

Answer (score 4):

In case you replace textarea elements by **class name**, just do this:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
    var editor = event.editor;

    editor.on('change', function(event) {
        // Sync textarea
        this.updateElement();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you have written will update the textarea of only one CKEditor at a time since it is adding a change event to each CKEditor. So this will always update the last element that has been changed.

The way I handle updation of multiple CKEditors is by using this code when submitting my form

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
   CKEDITOR.instances[i].updateElement();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I require the CKEditor to update each associated text area as the user enters data into the CKEditor when there is more than 1 CKEditor on the form - not when I submit the form. Any ideas?