# CKeditor issue with show hide on radio Button

Tags: ckeditor, hide, show

I have implemented CKeditor in one of my textarea. When i use radio button to show & hide textarea on click of radio button, javascript does not work..

After removing CKEditor from textarea.. javascript works properly..

**Below is the code of HTML :**

```
Option :
<input type="radio" name="adOption" id="adOption" value="Ads" data-rule-required="true"/> Ads
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="adOption" id="adOption" value="Page Content" data-rule-required="true" checked/> Page Content

Textarea :
<textarea name="pgContent" id="pgContent" class="ckeditor" data-rule-required="true" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>

TextBox :
  <input type="text" name="adUrl" id="adUrl" class="input-xxlarge" data-rule-required="true" />
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
                        if($(this).attr("value")=="Ads"){
                            document.getElementById("adURL").style.display="block"
                            document.getElementById("pgCon").style.display="none"
                        }
                        if($(this).attr("value")=="Page Content"){
                            document.getElementById("adURL").style.display="none"
                            document.getElementById("pgCon").style.display="block"
                        }                           
                    });
                });
```

What the issue, i m not getting. please help me for this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

See [the first paragraph of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581720/ckeditor-and-display-users-data-as-they-type/20610920#20610920) to find out how CKEditor actually works and how it deals with `<textarea>` to which it is attached.

`<textarea>` remains hidden as long as editor instance exists. You should manipulate editor UI instead. Use:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[ 'instanceName' ].container.hide(); // also container.show()
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.instances[ 'instanceName' ].container.$.style.display = '...';
```

to control visibility of the editor. Also see [`element.setStyle`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setStyle) method in CKEditor API.